# @ManyToOne seems not working as i expect it to be

Tags: jpa

I'm working with many-to-one relationship between my two tables(Employee and Department) in which any Employee can work in more than one department. I used the `@ManyToOne` annotation on the Department object field which I created in Employee entity class. Now when I persist the Employee entity with a particular department, it works fine but when I try to persist another Employee entity with the same department, it creates a new Department entity with the same name and persists it with different id. What I expect it to do is that when I persist an Employee entity with already persisted department, it should just update the foriegn key of the Employee entity to point the id of that department. Sorry if I didnt got the many-to-one concept totally.

```
EMPLOYEE entity
package com.test.domain;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

@Entity
public class Employee {

@TableGenerator(name="Empl_Gen", table="ID_GEN",pkColumnName="GEN_NAME",valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE", initialValue=0, allocationSize=1)
@Id@GeneratedValue(generator="Empl_Gen",strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;

private String Name;

private String Country;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="DEPT_ID")
private Department department;

public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return Country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    Country = country;
}

}
```

```
DEPARTMENT entity
package com.test.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

@Entity
public class Department {


@TableGenerator(name="DEP_GEN",table="ID_GEN",pkColumnName="GEN_NAME",valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE", pkColumnValue="DEP_GEN",initialValue=0,allocationSize=1)
@Id@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE,generator="DEP_GEN")
private Long id;

private String name;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}



package com.test.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.test.domain.Employee;
import com.test.service.EmployeeService;

/**
* Handles requests for the application home page.
*/
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/addEmployee")
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
EmployeeService service;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getform(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("employee",new Employee());

  return "home";

}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String setform(Employee employee)
{


    service.save(employee);
    return"success";
}
```

}

```
package com.test.dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.test.domain.Employee;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class Employeedaoimpl implements Employeedao 

{
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager manager;

@Override
public void save(Employee employee) {
    manager.persist(employee);


}
```

}

Comment: please add the code using which you are persisting those employees.

Comment: sir i have added my controller class code.. i m using a form to get the details of the employee and then persisting the the entity.i am also using the converter to convert the string(which i get from the form) to the DEPARTMENT entity object.

Comment: how have you created the department? in the ManyToOne mapping, somewhere you must be setting the department to an Employee. It should work that way. Here is the link which will be helpful for you. http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/15/jpa-many-one-association/

Comment: Could you also add the code of the `save(Employee)` method pls.

Comment: sir i m creating the department using the converter..and then it gets peristed itself  by using CascadeType.all

Comment: @PrasadKharkar sir, i am reading the tutorial. seems a good one. thanks

Comment: @tufailnazir sir, yeah you'll find lots of good jpa tutorials there :) I wrote them.

Comment: yup sir, saw you sneaking through your picture:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`@TableGenerator(name="DEP_GEN",table="ID_GEN",pkColumnName="GEN_NAME",valueColumnName="GEN_VALUE", pkColumnValue="DEP_GEN",initialValue=0,allocationSize=1)
@Id@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE,generator="DEP_GEN")
@Column(name = "DEPT_ID")
private Long id;`

Comment: did you drop the old table and run JPA model again? Be  sure that in your Department table you have a column named DEPT_ID and not "id"...